# Instrumenting java class using soot

Tags: soot

I'm trying to instrument byte code by converting it to jimple, adding code lines to jimple and compiling the jimple back to byte code. The problem is that I can't compile the jimple code back to byte code at all, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing? Normally Soot automatically outputs the corresponding .class files.